# Who can explain this setState call in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I came across this call and don't understand how it works, which concept is behind?

```
const todos = [...this.state.todos, todo]
this.setState({todos, inputValue:''}, () => { console.log(this.state)})
```

I was expecting

```
this.setState({todos: todos, inputValue:''}, () => { console.log(this.state)})
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `this.setState({todos})` this literally translates to `this.setState({todos: todos})`.
That is because when you just write a key without a value, the value becomes equal to the variable with the same name as this key (in your case it becomes equal to `const todos`).

Comment: Thank you, I understand now https://alligator.io/js/object-property-shorthand-es6/